# Permission to access existing photos on mobile with html 5

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I tried this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture></input>
```

But it only gives me permission to use the camera. Is it possible to get permission to access existing photos on a mobile device?

(I tried this on an LG G-3 with both the default browser and Chrome.)

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture></input>

Comment: You will not get access to files on user's file system through JavaScript unless the user voluntarily uploads those files